# InkToolbar is not supported in a Windows Universal project

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to add an InkCanvas with InkToolbar and I got this build error:

[image]

What's the matter with it?

Answer (score 3):

I changed the Target Version to `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (introduced v10.0.14393.0)` and it works now.

Comment: Yes, InkCanvas can be used atfer Anniversary Edition. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/synergist/2016/08/26/using-the-inktoolbar-with-custom-dry-ink-in-windows-anniversary-edition/